# How to send XMLHttpRequest Put call (error: too many redirects)

Tags: javascript, json, shopify

I can make GET calls fine, but I don't know how to make PUT requests. The error I'm getting is "Failed to load resource: too many HTTP redirects"

Code:

```
var url = "https://{{shop.domain}}/cart.js";    
var xhrPut = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrPut.open("PUT", url, true);
xhrPut.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhrPut.send("{\"total_price\":50}");
```

The JSON that I'm trying to change is this:

```
{"token":"a97c89f7e2c7c22becab8cfef40fa272","note":null,"attributes":{},"original_total_price":100,"total_price":100,"total_discount":0,"total_weight":0,"item_count":1,"items":[{"id":19673785606,"properties":null,"quantity":1,"variant_id":19673785606,"key":"19673785606:59d774c1f413525441dcb716e0c982e2","title":"Short Sleeve Shirt","price":100,"line_price":100,"original_line_price":100,"total_discount":0,"discounts":[],"sku":"","grams":0,"vendor":"Dev Store","product_id":6213990086,"gift_card":false,"url":"\/products\/short-sleeve-shirt?variant=19673785606","image":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/1278\/7069\/products\/happyman.jpg?v=1462811058","handle":"short-sleeve-shirt","requires_shipping":true,"product_type":"","product_title":"Short Sleeve Shirt","product_description":"description","variant_title":null,"variant_options":["Default Title"]}],"requires_shipping":true}
```

The total_price variable is currently 100, I'm trying to set it to 50.

Editing this so I may get answers

I changed the code to the following and then get error 400: bad request

```
var url = "https://{{shop.domain}}/cart.json";
var xhrPut = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrPut.open("PUT", url, false);
xhrPut.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhrPut.send('{"token":"a97c89f7e2c7c22becab8cfef40fa272","note":null,"attributes":{},"original_total_price":100,"total_price":50,"total_discount":0,"total_weight":0,"item_count":1,"items":[{"id":19673785606,"properties":null,"quantity":1,"variant_id":19673785606,"key":"19673785606:59d774c1f413525441dcb716e0c982e2","title":"Short Sleeve Shirt","price":100,"line_price":100,"original_line_price":100,"total_discount":0,"discounts":[],"sku":"","grams":0,"vendor":"Dev Store","product_id":6213990086,"gift_card":false,"url":"\\/products\\/short-sleeve-shirt?variant=19673785606","image":"https:\\/\\/cdn.shopify.com\\/s\\/files\\/1\\/1278\\/7069\\/products\\/happyman.jpg?v=1462811058","handle":"short-sleeve-shirt","requires_shipping":true,"product_type":"","product_title":"Short Sleeve Shirt","product_description":"description","variant_title":null,"variant_options":["Default Title"]}],"requires_shipping":true}"');
```

From my knowledge of how the PUT request works, this should overwrite the entire document, but the only changes made were:

- The variable total_cost was reduced from 100 to 50
- The escape character '\' was used before the characters '\' in the variable 'url' in the array 'item'

---

Here is a GET request that I am sending before this PUT request, which returns no errors and writes the expected values to console. Note that the errors with the PUT request occur whether this is run or commented out.

```
var totalCost;
var url = "https://{{shop.domain}}/cart.json";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {           
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {               
    var resp = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(resp);
    var json = JSON.parse(resp);
    console.log(json);                          
    totalCost = json.total_price;               
    console.log(totalCost);                                 
  }             
};          
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
xhr.send();
console.log(totalCost);
```

The only reason this is synchronous is so that I can log the totalCost after the API call.

Comment: I see that you are sending the request to another javascript file. That's not right. Check your server for the correct url to the resource

Comment: I changed the url to ".json", which redirected me to a page with the same information. I still got the same error.

Comment: That is a server issue normally.  Something is wrong with the resource being served and its response to the PUT verb.

Comment: I figure shopify doesn't want me to edit these values. If anyone using shopify has found a way to dynamically change the total cost in the cart by editing liquid files I would like to know.